# Is there a nicer way to write this type of nil check?

Tags: ruby

I have a few places in my code where I have nested objects, but can't guarantee they will always be set.

This could give me an ruby undefined method for nil:NilClass

```
puts obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.to_s
```

This check is ugly and repetitive:

```
if(obj1 && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3 && obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4)
  puts obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.to_s
end
```

Is there a concise way to write, if anything is nil just silently fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My version of try:

```
class Object
  def try(*args, &block)
    if args.empty? and block_given?
      begin
        instance_eval &block
      rescue NameError => e
        puts e.message + ' ' + e.backtrace.first
      end
    elsif respond_to?(args.first)
      send(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

So then instead of this long expression:

```
obj1.try(:obj2).try(:obj3).try(:obj4).to_s
```

you can do this:

```
obj1.try{ obj2.obj3.obj4.to_s }
```

**UPDATE:**
Made it a little cleaner

Comment: I like this! I'd actually like to see this packaged up similar to `andand` (and possibly renamed, e.g. `obj1.maybe { obj2.obj3.obj4.to_s }`.

Comment: Thanks, nice hint, i'll do the gem

Comment: I have written a gem which helps with this nicely - https://github.com/pzol/monadic so you can do Maybe(obj1).obj2.obj3.fetch('default') - where you can also provide a default if something on the way is nil. See also the Validation monad

Answer (score 4):

Or use [andand](http://andand.rubyforge.org/). I prefer this over symbols and find it more natural.

```
obj1.andand.obj2.andand.obj3.andand.obj4
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try). It's not from the Ruby library but you could easily add it to your project. So you'll be able to do:

```
obj1.try(:obj2).try(:obj3).try(:obj4)
```

Comment: Try is defined in ActiveSupport. You get it for free with Rails, otherwise you can just include it via `require "activesupport"`.

Comment: Requiring the entire ActiveSupport library just for `try` seems a little overkill, and potentially dangerous. (ActiveSupport's monkeypatching has [broken things for me in the past](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-sequel/issues/detail?id=329).) If you're going to use just this, I would `require "active_support/core_ext/object/try"`

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the [try approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159090/1177128) mentioned by lucapette you could also wrap that code in `begin; rescue; end` and just rescue `NameError`:

```rb
begin
    if(obj1 && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3 && obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4)
        puts obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.to_s
    end
rescue NameError
end
```

You can see the difference on this code:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/ruby

p :not_defined

begin
    if(obj1 && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3 && obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4)
        puts obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.to_s
    end
rescue NameError
    p :ouch
end

p :defined_all_the_way

class Yup
    def method_missing(m, *a, &b)
        self
    end

    def to_s
        :yup
    end
end
obj1 = Yup.new

begin
    if(obj1 && obj1.obj2 && obj1.obj2.obj3 && obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4)
        puts obj1.obj2.obj3.obj4.to_s
    end
rescue NameError
    p :ouch
end

__END__
Results in:
:not_defined
:ouch
:defined_all_the_way
yup
```

Comment: Note that if high-speed performance is important, using Exceptions like this can be [very slow](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/01/how-slow-are-ruby-exceptions/). Also note that some believe that [Exceptions should not be Expected](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/159807850/save-bang-your-head-active-record-will-drive-you-mad).

Comment: When are going to (ab)use Exceptions like this you can also make your code a hair simpler by using the form `s = foo.bar.baz.to_s rescue nil;`

Comment: @Phrogz: this will silently swallow all sorts of exceptions other than `NameError` that one might want to know about.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely have a better design that chained checks for nil objects. The pattern known as "Maybe monad" is particulary good at this exercise. First you have to properly wrap the untyped "Something or Nil" objects into proper "Maybe" objects. Then, in your case, your would simply write :

```
puts obj1.bind(&:obj2).bind(&:obj3).bind(&:obj4)
```

This is a functional programming style. If you want to give it a try, you can start with the [funkr gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/funkr) which is designed for [this can of usage](http://rubydoc.info/gems/funkr/0.0.28/Funkr/Types/Maybe).

Answer (score 0):

I think a bigger issue is violation of law of Demeter here. :-) You really should reconsider reaching into so many objects at once.