# Is there a faster to determine which object is nil in a serial dots?

Tags: ruby, try-catch, rescue

```
undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass
```

code:

```
a.b.c.d['test'].e['foo']
```

my solution:

```
puts "got it: #{a.inspect}"   if a.nil?
puts "got it: #{a.b.inspect}"   if a.b.nil?
puts "got it: #{a.b.c.inspect}"   if a.b.c.nil?
```

beside to handle production exception. I also to to find out the nil object faster in development stage.

[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159032/is-there-a-nicer-way-to-write-this-type-of-nil-check)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159032/is-there-a-nicer-way-to-write-this-type-of-nil-check)

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

However, modifying your code so it does not violate the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Of_Demeter) will separate these calls so there is only one call in the chain.

For example:

```
a.b.c
```

is bad because the place in which you call `c` doesn't have a representation of `c`, however, calling some method `d` in `a`'s class that returns `b.c` remedies this problem and you end up with just:

```
a.d
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an assignment in your code, so this code wouldn't produce that error. If you're worried about some of these being nil, then consider refactoring the code into methods, since when these are nil you'll get a nice stack trace:

```
  def a
    # wherever you get a from
  end

  def b
    a.b
  end

  # ... 

  def d(key)
    c.d["key"]
  end

  def e(key)
    d.e["key"]
  end

e("foo") = "value"
```

Yes, it's overkill, so the best method is to make sure that you don't return nils where you don't expect them, but if you need a good stacktrace from the logs, this will do the trick.